# NSPredicate with SUBQUERY does not work

Tags: ios, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I need to sort my fetch request with selected people, but it doesn't return anything

I tried this code with coredata objects comparing

```
NSPredicate *peoplePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(classPeople, $p, $p IN %@).@count == %d", self.selectedPeople, [self.selectedPeople count]];
```

and this with nsnumber iD comparing

```
NSPredicate *peoplePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(classPeople, $p, $p.iD IN %@).@count == %d", self.selectedPeopleiD, [self.selectedPeopleiD count]];
```

I have entity class, which has relationship people. And I have viewcontroller where I can select some people in list, after selecting people objects are adding to array self.selectedPeople, so I need to fetch all objects of Class entity, which has selected people

thanks in advance

Comment: You should explain your entities, attributes, relationships and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

So, then your predicate should look like:

```
NSPredicate *peoplePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY classPeople IN %@", self.selectedPeople];
```